# How "lock add" is implemented on x86 processors

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, atomic, cpu-architecture

I recently benchmarked `std::atomic::fetch_add` vs `std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong` on a 32 core Skylake Intel processor.  Unsurprisingly (from the myths I've heard about fetch_add), fetch_add is almost an order of magnitude more scalable than compare_exchange_strong.  Looking at the disassembly of the program `std::atomic::fetch_add` is implemented with a `lock add` and `std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong` is implemented with `lock cmpxchg` (https://godbolt.org/z/qfo4an).

What makes `lock add` so much faster on an intel multi-core processor? From my understanding, the slowness in both instructions comes from contention on the cacheline, and to execute both instructions with sequential consistency, the executing CPU has to pull the line into it's own core in exclusive or modified mode (from [MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)). How then does the processor optimize fetch_add internally?

---

[This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WwuVIx2jQlCYjHEl) is a simplified version of the benchmarking code.  There was no load+CAS loop for the compare_exchange_strong benchmark, just a compare_exchange_strong on the atomic with an input variable that kept getting varied by thread and iteration. So it was just a comparison of instruction throughput under contention from multiple CPUs.

Comment: You should show your benchmarking code as it's often where the problem lies.  Note that you'd have the same cache contention problems even if the LOCK prefix wasn't being used, as the CPU has to pull the cache line into memory for any write that's less than a full cache line width.

Comment: @RossRidge Edited the question with the benchmarking code.

Comment: Can you post the actual loops disassembly with actual numbers (iter/s)?

Comment: You didn't really benchmark `fetch_add()`. Because you didn't use the value that was fetched the compiler optimized it into an atomic "don't fetch, just add" and it's this "don't fetch, just add" that you benchmarked.

Comment: You can view locked instructions as taking a memory mutex: a mutex on the smallest portion of the memory system that can be locked by the memory access system. The way it works guarantees no deadlock can happen and the lock doesn't have to be optimistic (it never has to be cancelled).

Comment: @Brendan: `lock xadd` is presumably only a couple extra uops and not fundamentally different.  But fair point, that would be another thing the OP could test.

Answer (score 7):

`lock add` and `lock cmpxchg`  both work essentially the same way, by holding onto that cache line in Modified state for the duration of the microcoded instruction.  ([Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num)).  According to [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) instruction tables, `lock cmpxchg` and `lock add` are very similar numbers of uops from microcode.  (Although `lock add` is slightly simpler).   Agner's throughput numbers are for the uncontended case, where the var stays hot in L1d cache of one core.  And cache misses can cause uop replays, but I don't see any reason to expect a significant difference.

You claim you aren't doing load+CAS or using a retry loop.  But is it possible you're only counting successful CAS or something?  On x86, every CAS (including failures) has almost identical cost to `lock add`.  (With all your threads hammering on the same atomic variable, you'll get lots of CAS failures from using a stale value for `expected`.  This is not the usual use-case for CAS retry loops).

Or does your CAS version actually do a pure load from the atomic variable to get an `expected` value?  That might be leading to memory-order mis-speculation.

You don't have complete code in the question so I have to guess, and couldn't try it on my desktop.  You don't even have any perf-counter results or anything like that; there are lots of perf events for off-core memory access, and events like `mem_inst_retired.lock_loads` that could record number of `lock`ed instructions executed.

With `lock add`, every time a core gets ownership of the cache line, it succeeds at doing an increment.  Cores are only waiting for HW arbitration of access to the line, never for another core to get the line and then fail to increment because it had a stale value.

---

It's plausible that HW arbitration could treat `lock add` and `lock cmpxchg` differently, e.g. perhaps letting a core hang onto the line for long enough to do a couple `lock add` instructions.

Is that what you mean?

---

Or maybe you have some major failure in microbenchmark methodology, like maybe not doing a warm-up loop to get CPU frequency up from idle before starting your timing?  Or maybe some threads happen to finish early and let the other threads run with less contention?

Comment: Would the overhead of lock/cas operations be significant in a NUMA system, since cores are decentralized ?

Comment: @foool: Inter-core latency is higher, yes, so contention costs more.  And there are more cores that could all be contending for ownership of the same cache line.  But once a core has exclusive ownership of a cache line, everything is the same; uncontended atomic operations don't have to communicate outside the core, the cache line just stays in MESI Modified state.

Comment: BTW, looking at this question again, the 10x result could make sense if they were talking in terms of success of a CAS retry loop used to emulate `fetch_add`, since for operations that don't have hardware support (like `fetch_or` where you use the return value) a compiler does have to use a CAS retry loop, or where you manually want to roll your own atomic RMW of a single variable, like atomic right shift or atomic clear lowest set bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I should ask more specifically. Will the NUMA node lock a remote NUMA node's shared cache line for the purpose of updating the shared value atomically? The cost of the inter-processor contention should be higher than the cost of the Inter-core's.

Comment: @foool: NUMA systems are still cache-coherent.  A core doesn't have to tell other cores that it's locking the line, it just has to delay responding to MESI requests to share or invalidate the line until it's done, since no other core can even read the line while this core has it in Exclusive or Modified state.  See [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) for more details about the first sentence of this answer.  (Non-cache-coherent NUMA systems exist (shared-memory clusters), but we don't run threads across different nodes.)

Comment: Thanks for your reference, and I will dig more into this issue.

Comment: @foool: And just to be clear, a multi-socket server with multiple processors on one motherboard is cache-coherent across all cores in all sockets.  Non-cache-coherent NUMA is something you only find in clusters with special interconnects that allow shared memory at all between different rack units or even across cabinets.

Comment: 1 Your clarification reminds me of some fragments in the textbook. The non-cache-coherent NUMA systems should be more popular in mainframes or supercomputers, in which each node has its own local memory, and can not access the memory of a remote node directly. While I personally am more concerned about the cache-coherent NUMA systems. 
2 My doubt stems from the misunderstanding of the `lock`'s behavior, which is quite detailedly explained in your previous references. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> to execute both instructions **with sequential consistency**, the
>   executing CPU has to pull the line into it's own core in exclusive or
>   modified mode (from MESI).

No, to execute either instruction with any consistent, defined semantic that guarantees that concurrent executions on multiple CPU do not lose increments, you would need that. Even if you were willing to drop "sequential consistency" (on these instructions) or even drop the usual acquire and release guarantees of reads and writes.

Any locked instruction effectively *enforces mutual exclusion on the part of memory sufficient to guarantee atomicity*. (Like a regular mutex but at the memory level.)  Because no other core can access that memory range for the duration of the operation, the atomicity is trivially guaranteed.

> What makes lock add so much faster on an intel multi-core processor?

I would expect any tiny difference of timing to be critical in these cases, and doing the load plus compare (or compare-load plus compare-load ...) might change the timing enough to lose the chance, much like too code using mutexes can have widely different efficiency when there is heavy contention and a small change in access pattern changes the way the mutex is attributed.